# Метка не отображается в топе

Tags: дефект, метки

В [моем профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/106/andreycha?tab=profile) топ-6 меток выглядит следующим образом. Шестая метка [wpf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) имеет рейтинг 28.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом если перейти в [полный список меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/106/andreycha?tab=tags), то ввидно, что топ-6 выглядит по-другому.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: почему в "главный" топ не попадает метка [`юнит-тесты`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B/info)?

Comment: а у меня совпадает. Но недавно вроде спрашивали что-то похожее и говорили, что возможно тут еще последняя активность по метке учитывается

Comment: Возможно, дело в том, что юнит-тесты только недавно набрали 100 вопросов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin да уже несколько месяцев как. Многовато для обновления. По моим наблюдениям пересчет по метка максимум сутки-двое занимает.